# How to applly Hanning window on S parameter results?

Tags: transfer-function, window-functions, ifft

I am working on Time domain computation. I have S parameter results simulated, using these results I do the Inverse FFT to get results in time domain. 
I want to filter/window results using Hanning window. 
In frequency domain, I need to do the multiplication of the function of this filter in frequency and the S parameter results. So, I will loop on N:number of frequencies and multiply each results by the Hann window. How can I compute the length of the filter L??
[image]

Comment: May I know whether the S-parameters are of low-pass or band-pass filter, if they are relevant to the discussion?

Comment: So if I follow, you want to window the frequency domain data prior to taking the IFFT, I assume to reduce ringing in the derived time domain impulse response. (Multiply each complex sample in frequency with the Hann window and then take IFFT). If that is the case the number of samples in your window should match the number of samples in your frequency vector. You can get the window coefficients directly in Matlab using hann(N)